# Implement Row Level security column in inherited tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, row-level-security, ef-code-first-mapping

I'm using Entity Framework with a code-first approach to generate the database. I have introduced row-Level security in SQL Server.

I want to create 3 tables where all the common properties go to `ItemVersion` and document related properties to `DocumentVersion` and form related things to `FormVersion` so and so. I'm supposed to introduce row level security column `TenantId` in all 3 tables.

```
interface ITenantSecurityPolicy
{
    int TenantId { get; set; }
}

public class ItemVersion : ITenantSecurityPolicy
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CreatedPersonId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
}

[Table("DocumentVersions")]
public class DocumentVersion : ItemVersion
{
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string DocumentVersionNumber { get; set; }
    public int FileId { get; set; }
}

[Table("FormVersions")]
public class FormVersion : ItemVersion
{
    public string DesignerContentId { get; set; }
}
```

When I generate the database, it does not create the `TenantId` in child classes - the column `TenantId` is created only in the `ItemVersion` table.

How do I handle this situation? Are there any workaround or suggestions?

Comment: Which EF version are you in?

Comment: The installed version is 6.1.3

Comment: Normally, EF should create tables for the two subtypes only, including all columns of the base type. Have you any additional mappings?

Comment: Yes. I'm using Table splitting using Data Annotation. Note that DocumentVersion and FomVersion have `[Table("FormVersions")]` annotations.

Comment: Yes, I know, but the model *as you show it* shouldn't create an `ItemVersion` table.

Comment: Actually, it does. As an additional thing what I have is `        public virtual DbSet<BusinessItemVersion> BusinessItemVersions { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<DocumentVersion> DocumentVersions { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<FormVersion> FormVersions { get; set; }` in my context class.

Comment: So that's what tells EF to create `(Business)ItemVersion` table. Which means that you have a TPT inheritance scheme now. I think you shouldn't map the base class, so EF will map all subtypes independently.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is also probably the right relational design for a multi-tenant schema:  make the TenantId the leading column in the primary key.

```
public class ItemVersion : ITenantSecurityPolicy
{
    [Key,Column(Order=0)]
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
    [Key,Column(Order=1),DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CreatedPersonId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

}
```